# Drupal-vm port forward

Tags: vagrant

I have drupalvm setup which has drupal installed. In my custom theme, I have styleguide running on port 6006 (can be configured to different as well as it's node app). I want to expose this to host system. when I do `vagrant ssh -- -L 6006:localhost:6006` it's works fine and available on host. Now I have added below to Vagrantfile to make this permanent (as per document here - http://docs.drupalvm.com/en/latest/extending/vagrantfile/):

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 6006, host: 6006
end
```

Now I can see this port forwarded when I do `vagrant port` But I can't access localhost:6006 (or use already working drupal hostname - local.drupal.com:6006) on host machine. Do I have to add vhost for it in vagrant, if yes how? OR is there any other way to expose node app to host?